# Method to update my model's new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named `UserPrice` which has a form where you can create many `UserPrice's` at once. I have this virtual attribute called `:all_dates` which is suppose to update another date_select field of my `UserPrice` model called `:purchase_date` but since it isn't doing its job correctly I need a detailed explanation on this method here so I can get it to work:

```
def save_all_dates_to_user_prices
 if !self.all_dates.nil?
 self.user_prices.each {|up| up.purchase_date = self.all_dates if up.new_record?}
 end
end
```

I'll start out:

1. I defined the method `save_all_dates_to_user_prices` to happen
   `before_save` in my UserPrice model.
2. `if !self.all_dates.nil?` means the UserPrice.all_dates attribute is being check if it is blank or not there (nil?).

This is where I get lost; not being sure on this line:

```
self.user_prices.each {|up| up.purchase_date = self.all_dates if up.new_record?}
```

- Its wrapping each UserPrice.user_prices? It wouldn't look like this if I am trying to get an Array of new records right?
- Why use `|up|`, is that the `self.user_prices.each` stands for?
- `self.user_prices.each` = anything wrapped in the `{}` (hashes)?

Along with answering the questions I have above could someone fill/correct the details for me about this method?

Thanks, I am new to Rails and Ruby trying to learn as I code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each` is a method of the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html) class, which both Array and Hash implement. It takes a block as an argument and simply applies it to all the elements of the Enumerable. So the line you're asking about translates like this:

for each for the `user_prices`, assign `all_dates` to `purchase_date` if it's a new `user_price`

The `up` is just a variable referring to the current Enumerale element.

Here's a [good explanation of closures in ruby](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/).

Answer (score 2):

That's kind of a clunky bit of Ruby code, so here's a break-down of it, slightly rewritten:

```
def save_all_dates_to_user_prices
  # If all_dates is defined...
  if (self.all_dates)
    # ...then for each entry in user_prices hereby called 'up'...
    self.user_prices.each do |up|
      # ...check if this is a new record...
      if (up.new_record?)
         # ...and assign the purchase_date
         up.purchase_date = self.all_dates
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you're familiar with JavaScript, then `x.each { |y| ... }` in Ruby is similar to `x.each(function(y) { ... })` in JavaScript with jQuery. The variables inside the vertical bars represent arguments to that function block in both cases.